# Asterisk GoSub() function not working for me

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I am trying to make calls between extensions 101 and 102 and is NOT going through. I have the following extensions.conf file

```
[general]
autofallthrough=no
priorityjumping=yes
static=yes
writeprotect=no
clearglobalvars=yes

[default]
exten => .,1,Hangup()

[inbound-schedule]
; #_#_# Phone Number #_#_#
exten => 7867086699,1,Answer
exten => 7867086699,n,NoOp(Office-ANI-${EXTEN})
exten => 7867086699,n,Set(CDR(userfield)=ib_${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}_${EXTEN}_${CALLERID(num)})
exten => 7867086699,n,MixMonitor(ib_${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}_${EXTEN}_${CALLERID(num)}.wav)
exten => 7867086699,n,Goto(schedule,${EXTEN},1)

exten => .,1,Hangup()

[schedule]
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,NoOp(Time-of-Day-Routing)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIfTime(8:58-17:02,mon-fri,*,*?inbound,${EXTEN},1)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Goto(inbound-closed,${EXTEN},1)

[inbound]
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,NoOp(Office-Open)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(NUMINVALID=1)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(TIMEOUT(digit)=3)  ; max wait in-between digits seconds 
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(TIMEOUT(response)=3)  ; max wait for digit entry seconds
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Ringing
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n(menu),Wait(1)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Background(custom/open-recording)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Wait(3)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Background(custom/open-recording)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Wait(3)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/101,18)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Voicemail(100@default,su)

exten => 0,1,NoOp(Office-Open-Press-Zero)
exten => 0,n,Voicemail(100@default,su)

exten => 2,1,NoOp(Operator-Directory)
exten => 2,n,Directory(default,vm-operator,f)

exten => 200,1,NoOp(External-Voicemail-Dial-From-${CALLERID(num)})
exten => 200,n,Playback(vm-dialout)
exten => 200,n,Wait(1)
exten => 200,n,VoiceMailMain()

exten => _1XX,1,Macro(local-followme,${EXTEN})

exten => t,1,Playback(option-is-invalid)
exten => t,n,Hangup()

exten => i,1,Set(NUMINVALID=$[${NUMINVALID}+1]})
exten => i,n,Playback(option-is-invalid)
exten => i,n,Gotoif($["${NUMINVALID}" < "4"]?:10)
exten => i,n,Goto(_NXXNXXXXXX,menu)
exten => i,10,Playback(vm-goodbye)
exten => i,n,Hangup()

[inbound-closed]
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,NoOp(Office-Closed)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(NUMINVALID=1)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(TIMEOUT(digit)=3)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(TIMEOUT(response)=3)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Ringing
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n(menu),Wait(1)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Background(custom/closed-recording)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Wait(3)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Background(custom/closed-recording)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Wait(3)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/101,18)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Voicemail(100@default,su)

exten => 0,1,NoOp(Office-Open-Press-Zero)
exten => 0,n,Voicemail(100@default,su)

exten => 2,1,NoOp(Operator-Directory)
exten => 2,n,Directory(default,vm-operator,f)

exten => 200,1,NoOp(External-Voicemail-Dial-From-${CALLERID(num)})
exten => 200,n,Playback(vm-dialout)
exten => 200,n,Wait(1)
exten => 200,n,VoiceMailMain()

exten => _1XX,1,Macro(local-followme,${EXTEN})

exten => t,1,Playback(option-is-invalid)
exten => t,n,Hangup()

exten => i,1,Set(NUMINVALID=$[${NUMINVALID}+1]})
exten => i,n,Playback(option-is-invalid)
exten => i,n,Gotoif($["${NUMINVALID}" < "4"]?:10)
exten => i,n,Goto(_NXXNXXXXXX,menu)
exten => i,10,Playback(vm-goodbye)
exten => i,n,Hangup()

[outbound]
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@voip-outbound,120,trwW)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Hangup()

exten => .,1,Playback(invalid)
exten => .,n,Hangup()

[internal]
; #_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_# INTERNAL MAIN CONTEXT #_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

; Extension to Extension Dialing
exten => _1XX,1,Macro(local-followme,${EXTEN})

; Call Pickup
exten => _*971XX,1,SET(GLOBAL(PICKUPMARK)=${EXTEN:2})
exten => _*971XX,n,Pickup(${EXTEN:2}@PICKUPMARK)

; Voicemail Access
exten => 1000,1,VoiceMailMain(${CALLERID(num)}@default)
exten => 2000,1,VoiceMailMain()

; Outbound Dialing
exten => _NXXXXXX,1,Answer
exten => _NXXXXXX,n,Set(CDR(userfield)=ib_${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}_${EXTEN}_${CALLERID(num)})
exten => _NXXXXXX,n,MixMonitor(ob_${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}_${EXTEN}_${CALLERID(num)}.wav)
exten => _NXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=7867086699)
exten => _NXXXXXX,n,Goto(outbound,310${EXTEN},1)

exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,Answer
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(CDR(userfield)=ib_${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}_${EXTEN}_${CALLERID(num)})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,MixMonitor(ob_${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}_${EXTEN}_${CALLERID(num)}.wav)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=7867086699)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Goto(outbound,${EXTEN},1)

exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,1,Answer
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(CDR(userfield)=ib_${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}_${EXTEN}_${CALLERID(num)})
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,MixMonitor(ob_${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}_${EXTEN}_${CALLERID(num)}.wav)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=7867086699)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Goto(outbound,${EXTEN:1},1)

exten => t,1,Playback(invalid)
exten => t,n,Hangup()
exten => i,1,Playback(invalid)
exten => i,n,Hangup()
exten => .,1,Playback(invalid)
exten => .,n,Hangup()

[macro-local-followme]
exten => s,1,GotoIf($[${DB_EXISTS(followme/${ARG1})}=0]?nofollow)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($[${DB_RESULT:0:1}=0]?nofollow:follow)
exten => s,n(follow),Dial(SIP/${ARG1},20)
exten => s,n,Followme(${ARG1},n)                      ; Removed sa so no name recording
exten => s,n,Goto(s-${DIALSTATUS},1)
exten => s,n(nofollow),Dial(SIP/${ARG1},20)
exten => s,n,Goto(s-${DIALSTATUS},1)
exten => s-NOANSWER,1,Voicemail(${ARG1},u)            ; If unavailable, send to voicemail
exten => s-BUSY,1,Voicemail(${ARG1},u)                ; I changed b to u. If busy, send to voicemail w/ busy ann
exten => _s-.,1,Goto(s-NOANSWER,1)

[outbound-follow-me]
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,NoOp(follow-me-activated-${EXTEN})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${IF($[ ${LEN(${CALLERID(num)})} = 3]?7867086699:${CALLERID(num)})})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Goto(outbound,${EXTEN},1)

exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,1,NoOp(follow-me-activated-${EXTEN})
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${IF($[ ${LEN(${CALLERID(num)})} = 3]?7867086699:${CALLERID(num)})})
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Goto(outbound,${EXTEN:1},1)

exten => _1XX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},120,t)
exten => _1XX,n,Hangup()

[vm-operator]
exten => o,1,NoOp(operator-zero-out)
exten => o,n,Goto(vm-zero-menu,s,1)

; Direct Extension Dialing
exten => _1XX,1,Macro(local-followme,${EXTEN})

[vm-zero-menu]
exten => s,1,NoOp(operator-asterisk-out)
exten => s,n,Set(TIMEOUT(digit)=3)
exten => s,n,Set(TIMEOUT(response)=3)
exten => s,n,Background(custom/vm-operator-recording)
exten => s,n,Wait(3)
exten => s,n,Voicemail(100@default,su)

exten => 0,1,Voicemail(100@default,su)

exten => 1,1,NoOp(Operator-Directory)
exten => 1,n,Directory(default,vm-operator,f)

exten => 2,1,Voicemail(100@default,su)
exten => 3,1,Voicemail(100@default,su)
exten => 4,1,Voicemail(100@default,su)
exten => 5,1,Voicemail(100@default,su)
exten => 6,1,Voicemail(100@default,su)
exten => 7,1,Voicemail(100@default,su)
exten => 8,1,Voicemail(100@default,su)
exten => 9,1,Voicemail(100@default,su)

; Direct Extension Dialing
exten => _1XX,1,Macro(local-followme,${EXTEN})

exten => t,1,Playback(invalid)
exten => t,n,Hangup()
exten => i,1,Playback(invalid)
exten => i,n,Hangup()
exten => .,1,Playback(invalid)
exten => .,n,Hangup()
```

I got the following error:

```
Executing [102@internal:1] Gosub("SIP/101-00000002", "local-followme,s,1(102)") in new stack
[2021-05-18 20:26:16] ERROR[19823][C-0000000a]: app_stack.c:593 gosub_exec: Attempt to reach a non-existent destination for Gosub: (Context:local-followme, Extension:s, Priority:1)
  == Spawn extension (internal, 102, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/101-00000002'
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
```

app_stack is loaded apparently, this is what I have with the command "module show like app_stack" on CLI

app_stack.so - Dialplan subroutines (Gosub, Return, etc 0 - Running - core

I will really appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

Comment: What is not clear for you in your error output?

Comment: I would like to know how come I am unable to make calls between extensions. Whenever I place a call I get the error message that is show in my question.

Comment: Maybe because you have no local-followme context at all, don't you? Common, asterisk can't write dialplan for you and guess what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I am new at this and I will keep on practicing. I really appreciate your help. That was the issue, now is fully functional.

Comment: There isn't even a `Gosub()` call in your dialplan...

Comment: Instead of repeating `exten => _NXXNXXXXXX` several times, use `same =>`.  It will save you hours of debugging when you accidentally have replaced a character. It also makes it easier for a human to read.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm if you are reloading the dialplan module by "dialplan reload" command in Asterisk CLI, it seems like what is being executed in the call is GoSub instead of Macro. You can validate dialplan statements loaded in Asterisk by doing "dialplan show" or "dialplan show context-name"

Please, avoid using Macro application, you should use GoSub application instead, Macro is considered deprecated.

Here's a Gosub example:

```
[internal]
exten => _1XX,1,GoSub(local-followme,s,1(${EXTEN}))

[local-followme]
exten => s,1,Verbose(GoSub executing)
same = n,Verbose(Argument 1: ${ARG1})
same = n,Return()
```